# Batch to move file into sub directories excluding parent directory

Tags: batch-file, copy

I have a `.otf` file that I would like to copy into all the sub directories of the parent folder. This is what I have attempted.

```
for /R %%x in (.) do copy "file.otf" "%%x"
```

This works for the most part but it also leaves a copy into the parent folder. I would like to fix this such the the batch only copies into all the sub directories.

Comment: `set "FLAG=" & for /R %%x in (.) do if defined FLAG (copy "file.otf" "%%~x") else (set "FLAG=#")`? (this should work since the parent is iterated first)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `for /R %%x in (.)` is going to return the parent directory in the first iteration, you could use a flag-like variable to skip the `copy` command by an [`if` condition](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) in the first loop iteration, like this:

```cmd
set "FLAG="
for /R %%x in (.) do (
    if defined FLAG (
        copy "file.otf" "%%~x"
    ) else (
        set "FLAG=#"
    )
)
```

---

According to [Squashman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1417694)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55337834/batch-to-move-file-into-sub-directories-excluding-parent-directory/55338415#comment97408040_55338415), an even easier option would be to use `for /D /R` to only enumerate sub-directories:

```cmd
for /D /R %%x in (*) do (
    copy "file.otf" "%%~x"
)
```

Comment: Another option would be to use `for /D /R %%G IN (*) do copy "file.otf" "%%~G\"`